# Symfony - npm update not fixing vulnerabilities

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony using the book on the site and when I type at cmd:

> symfony deploy

Then it says

```
Symfony Security Check Report
1 package has known vulnerabilities.

symfony/http-kernel (v5.0.11)
[CVE-2020-15094][]: Prevent RCE when calling untrusted remote with CachingHttpClient
[CVE-2020-15094]: https://symfony.com/cve-2020-15094
Note that this checker can only detect vulnerabilities that are referenced in the security advisories database.
Execute this command regularly to check the newly discovered vulnerabilities.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: i think an update has already been patched for this issue. simply update your package

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed. It's perfectly clear.

Comment: The solution is to check out the book project with a newer Symfony version. See [Getting the Project Source Code](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/2-project.html#getting-the-project-source-code) for the latest, or use `symfony new --book --version=stable`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I've moved on since then but I'm glad you found an answer

Answer (score 3):

Simply update the package.

You can review the versions and which ones that has reportedly an vulnerability inside it here: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-kernel

> composer update symfony/http-kernel

Comment: How do I update the package? I just started using it this morning

Comment: composer update symfony/http-kernel

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. No update gets applied, and `symfony deploy` still fails with the same error.

Comment: If this does not work, you can also change `"symfony/http-kernel": "5.4.*"` to `"symfony/http-kernel": "^5.4.0"` in your your composer.json file. Then run `composer update`. It will update all your packages to their newest version.  PS: in my case i use symfony version `5.4`, use whatever version you have in composer file.